# How to keep data for a service after swiping off the application

Tags: android, android-activity, background, android-service

Developing an android application where a background service continuously gets user location. It alarm user when he/she is about to reach destination specified by user.

To do so, I've to compare current location with the target location. The target location is acquired from another activity. Now when iam swiping off the application, the background service is running but is not able to compare with the cuurent location as the target destination coordinates is blank.

How to rectify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target location could be saved to a shared preference or a database or broadcast in an `Intent` from the Activity whenever it is changed. This will allow your Service to compare against it even if the Activity is no longer running.